# Copy 2D array within object by reference

Tags: java, java-7

Object1.java:

```
public class Object1 {
    public double[][] var1;
    ...
}
```

Object2.java:

```
public class Object2 {
    public double[][] var2;
    ...
}
```

I want to copy by reference (shallow copy) Object2.var2 into Object1.var1. Here's what I'm trying, which isn't working:

```
 Object1 object1 = new Object1();
 object1.var1 = new double[2][];
 System.arraycopy(object2.var2, 0, object1.var1, 0, object2.var2.length);
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong? I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` compile error. Note that `object2.var2` is populated with data.

UPDATE 1:

Note that object2.var2 is an Nx2 matrix, which looks like:

```
object2.var2[0][0]=1.232
object2.var2[0][1]=23.233
object2.var2[1][0]=3.23
object2.var2[1][1]=32.12
...
object2.var2[N][0]=3.23
object2.var2[N][1]=32.12
```

I also see `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try the following:

```
object1.var1=new double[object2.var2.length][2];
object1.var1=object2.var2;
```

Comment: If you want to actually copy references, you sould use `public List<List<Double>> var = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();` Otherwise this is a duplicate of things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269018/copying-a-two-dimensional-array-still-uses-references

Comment: "copy by reference" != "shallow copy"

Comment: OK, copy by reference, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Object2 object2 = new Object2();    
    // you need to iniialize ur object2.var2 first
    object2.var2 = new double[][]{ {1.232, 23.233},{3.23,32.12},{3.23,32.12}};
    //or 
    object2.var2 = new double[3][2];
    object2.var2[0][0]=1.232;
    object2.var2[0][1]=23.233;
    object2.var2[1][0]=3.23;
    object2.var2[1][1]=32.12;
    object2.var2[2][0]=3.23;
    object2.var2[2][1]=32.12;

    System.out.println(object2.var2);
    Object1 object1 = new Object1();
    object1.var1= new double[object2.var2.length][2];
    System.out.println(object1.var1);
    System.arraycopy(object2.var2, 0, object1.var1, 0, object2.var2.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I finally got it working using your example.

Comment: This isn't what you want (or at least what you said you wanted). This is only half a shallow copy. It creates a new array to hold row references, but then stores the same row references as the original array. With this, modifying a cell in one array would be reflected in the other, although replacing an entire row (`object1.var1[n] = new double[]`) would not affect the other. It is an unusual case; are you *sure* this is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You say you want a shallow copy, but it looks like you are half attempting a deep copy. For a shallow copy, all you have to do is copy the reference; no array allocation or copying necessary:

```
object1.var1 = object2.var2;
```

Example:

```
public class Example {
    public static final void main (String[] args) {
        double[][] d = new double[10][10];
        double[][] e = d;    
        d[3][3] = 1.234;
        System.out.println(e[3][3]);
    }
}
```

Output is `1.234`.

Comment: what would it look like if `e` and `d` where inside another Object? Perhaps my initializations are wrong.

Comment: It would look like `object1.e = object2.d`, which is exactly what I wrote at the beginning of the post above. :)

Comment: I suggest reading through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating one dimension of the array but not the other(s) even in your original matrix!

double var1=new double[2][]; //isn't enough

Think of a matrix as an array of arrays--you allocated the array of arrays but not the internal arrays themselves.  If you wanted your second dimension to be 3 for a 2x3 matrix, you need to:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < var1.length; i ++)
    var1[i]=new double[3]
```

Now your matrix is allocated.  the copy will go pretty much the same way.

to copy an arbitrary matrix in var1 to var2, you probably want:

```
var2=new double[var1.length][];

for(int i=0 ; i < var1.length; i ++)
{
    var2[i]=new double[var1[i]];
    System.arraycopy(object2.var2[i], 0, object1.var1[i], 0, object2.var2[i].length);
}
```

I don't do this much, but I think that's pretty accurate.

that said, there is usually a better way.  If you are going to use matrices a lot you might want to look into some free external libraries.

Comment: This describes a deep copy. The OP wanted a shallow copy - although it's confusing because his code was halfway to a deep copy.

Comment: A deep copy would be copying each object within the matrix.  Making a shalow copy of the matrix is what he asked for, not a shallow copy of the variable pointing to the matrix.

Comment: You *are* making a copy of each object within the matrix. The matrix contains primitive `double`s... what you describe here is a 100% proper deep copy. :)

Comment: Ahh, I guess you're right.  If it were a Double it would be different, but since Java inlines doubles... Hmph.  Anyway, I think that's what he was after from his example.